# How to extract only those numbers that are in a specific pattern from mixed text in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to extract a specific pattern of numbers from mixed text in Excel.  Considerations:

1. The number to be extracted always has the pattern `99.99.999.999`
2. The string it is contained in is of varied length, and the position of the numbers to be extracted also vary.
3. There are no characters in the beginning or end of the required numbers, based on which they can be extracted

Examples:

```
01.11.202.037.2011_20171017150732.pdf  
01.26.304.012.09.re_20170621163250.pdf  
01.36.402.010 MAI 2011.pdf  
2011.mai.01.02.203.001_20170802112610.pdf  
lease_20161104110041.pdf  
re.01.02.203.001.2012_20171019085424.pdf  
16.20.116.014.14re_20170621161637.pdf
```

Result should be:

```
01.11.202.037  
01.26.304.012  
01.36.402.010  
01.02.203.001  
NA  
01.02.203.001  
16.20.116.014
```

Comment: You can use this answer to make your self a regex cell function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43128681/1011724, now your question is just how to identify numbers like 99.99.999.999 in regex and according to [this site](https://www.regular-expressions.info/ip.html) you can do it like this `\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}`

Comment: This worked, thank you. There are some cases, that dint work for eg. when prefix includes numbers and dots, but as 9999. Example: re.2009.18.31.300.016.pdf. The result should be 18.31.300.016, but comes out as 09.18.31.300. But these instances are far too few, so overall this solution worked...

Comment: you could probably adjust the regex expression to exclude patterns that begin with 4 digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something using Regular Expressions.  It works on all your examples and it also checks that the first and last segments are no more than two or three digits respectively:

```
Option Explicit
Function ExtractNumPattern(S As String) As String
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object
    Const sPat As String = "(?:^|\D)(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{3}\.\d{3})(?:\D|$)"

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = False
    .Pattern = sPat
    .MultiLine = True
    If .Test(S) = True Then
        Set MC = .Execute(S)
        ExtractNumPattern = MC(0).submatches(0)
    Else
        ExtractNumPattern = "NA"
    End If
End With
End Function
```

[image]

The regex pattern should be fairly clear except, perhaps, for the beginning and the end.

The first part `(?:^|\D)` ensures that the value is preceded by either a non-digit or the beginning of the line.

The last part `(?:\D|$)` ensures that the value is followed by either a non-digit or the end of the line.

Comment: @g_profile Your welcome. If this is the best answer, could you please accept it?  See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Such overkill, why do you always go to VBA, I would just do

```
=MID(A1,SEARCH("??.??.???.???",A1),13)
```

And drag down the formula, oh yes, and include an error correction for values without it

```
=IFERROR(MID(A1,SEARCH("??.??.???.???",A1),13),"NA")
```

[image]

Comment: The problem with this is, it does not check whether they are only numerals. For eg. re.09.362.227.004.2015.pdf gives result as re.09.362.227 whereas it should be NA. Similarly, it considers 9999 component as well, while it should not be considered. For eg. re.13.09.33.005.2012.pdf gives 09.33.005.201, while it should be NA.
However this is a very simple and straightforward solution, and fails only for NA situations.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a pretty simple to follow VBA function,

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestIt()
  Dim c As Range
  For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Debug.Print c, ParsedAddr(c)
  Next c
End Sub

Function ParsedAddr(c As Range) As String
  Dim i As Long, iLen As Long

  iLen = Len(c)
  For i = 1 To iLen - 12
    If IsNumeric(Mid(c, i, 1)) Then                              '9
      If IsNumeric(Mid(c, i + 1, 1)) Then                        '99
        If Mid(c, i + 2, 1) = "." Then                           '99.
          If IsNumeric(Mid(c, i + 3, 1)) Then                    '99.9
            If IsNumeric(Mid(c, i + 4, 1)) Then                  '99.99
              If Mid(c, i + 5, 1) = "." Then                     '99.99.
                If IsNumeric(Mid(c, i + 6, 1)) Then              '99.99.9
                  If IsNumeric(Mid(c, i + 7, 1)) Then            '99.99.99
                    If IsNumeric(Mid(c, i + 8, 1)) Then          '99.99.999
                      If Mid(c, i + 9, 1) = "." Then             '99.99.999.
                        If IsNumeric(Mid(c, i + 10, 1)) Then     '99.99.999.9
                          If IsNumeric(Mid(c, i + 11, 1)) Then   '99.99.999.99
                            If IsNumeric(Mid(c, i + 12, 1)) Then '99.99.999.999
                              Exit For
                            End If
                          End If
                        End If
                      End If
                    End If
                  End If
                End If
              End If
            End If
          End If
        End If
      End If
    End If
  Next i
  If i < iLen - 11 Then
    ParsedAddr = Mid(c, i, 13)
  Else
    ParsedAddr = "NA"
  End If
End Function
```

VBA will indeed let you nest all that you want, so there! You could condense this code massively using subroutines - e.g. searching for characters of format "99." or "999." - but, though it's not "tight" it's pretty :) I'm leaving this bare though so it's extremely simple to follow.

I wrote this as a function so it can be adapted to output parsed strings into cells.

Comment: This got downvoted? Really? THIS reply did??? Totally awesome. Ah, superuser - where the name of the game is to downvote everyone else, because the downvoter "relatively" ascends. Well at least I'll know what to expect during the zombie apocalypse. Thanks to this jolting of my perspective, now I'll see you coming and be ready instead of assuming that everyone is in it to help each other. Thanks for the wake up call on that! Looking forward to thanking you personally during zombie apocalypse, downvoter!

Answer (score 0):

This question was really picking my brain so I decided to give it my own shot. I think that [Ron Rosenfeld](https://superuser.com/users/366681/ron-rosenfeld)'s response is pretty [straightforward](https://superuser.com/a/1288748/814906) and perhaps a bit more elagant; so definitely consider that method first.

**I'm using the following methodology**:

1. Turn the string into a simple pattern; periods equal **0**s and all other characters equal **1**s.
2. Then search for the pattern the OP asks for; ##.##.###.### = 1101101110111
3. The search returns the starting index of the pattern--from that index, return 13 numbers.

The additional code, as usual, is there to catch errors, provide a small performance boost (tested with 5k duplicate records), and help improve the logic.

**Below, is an image of the xlsm layout:**

[IMAGE LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rc6ow.png)

Please visit this [Code Review post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/186206/excel-vba-retrieving-a-specific-pattern-from-string) for a more in depth analysis by [Thomas Inzina](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/109261/thomas-inzina) and pointers from [AJD](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/157102/ajd), who helped enhance the quality of the code below.

---

```
Sub PatternScrub()

Dim Pattern As String
Dim x As Integer
Dim data As Variant
Dim Target As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set Target = .Range("A1", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

data = Target.Value

    PerformanceBoost True

        For x = 1 To UBound(data)
            If data(x, 1) Like "*##.##.###.###*" Then
                data(x, 1) = getPatternValue(CStr(data(x, 1)))
            Else
                data(x, 1) = "NA"
            End If
        Next

        Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = data

    PerformanceBoost False

End Sub

Private Function Pattering(ByVal Target As String) As String

Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To Len(Target)
       Mid(Target, i, 1) = IIf(Mid(Target, i, 1) = ".", 0, 1)       'TURNS THE STRING INTO 1s AND 0s
    Next

Pattering = Target

End Function

Private Function PatternIndex(ByVal Pattern As String) As Integer

    On Error Resume Next
    PatternIndex = Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("1101101110111", Pattern)       ' MATCHES THE PATTERN AND RETURNS THE FIRST INDEX

End Function

Private Function getPatternValue(Text As String) As String

    Dim x As Long
    x = PatternIndex(Pattering(Text))
    getPatternValue = Mid(Text, x, 13)

End Function

Sub PerformanceBoost(TurnOn As Boolean)

    With Application
        .Calculation = IIf(Turn, xlCalculationManual, xlCalculationAutomatic)
        .ScreenUpdating = Not TurnOn
        .DisplayStatusBar = Not TurnOn
        .EnableEvents = Not TurnOn
    End With

End Sub
```